# Dataflow import - products not showing after import

Tags: import, products, dataflow

I have a file with new products. I am trying to import the products. every thing is working as it should be it is running in popup and no error what so ever.

but the products are not showing up on my admin panel neither on front end.

for your reference I have been using this method from day one but suddenly it stop working this item. regarding any new extension. yes I have installed new extension for sage pay. but I don't think this relate with import system. I have checked all the heading and matched with new exported file and match the data every thing seems ok.

I have made another change. I have deleted var/package files which some one told me not important, can this be a problem?

I need help guys. I don't have much of technical know how but can change things by reading instruction, so your quick help will be very handy.

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem,

for other people getting same issue.

I had a space [ ] in front of enabled. it was like this "Enabled " so I deleted the extra space and it is perfect now.